# Python Emailing - Use of colon causes no output

Tags: python, email

Really odd experience with this which took me over an hour to figure out. I have a cgi script written in python which takes form data and forwards it to an email, the problem was, if there was a colon in the string it would cause python to output nothing to the email.

Does anyone know why this is?

For example:

```
output = "Print- Customer"
```

works, though:

```
output = "Print: Customer"
```

prints no output.

My email function works essentially:

```
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
```

where msg = output

Just wondering if the colon is a special character in python string output

Comment: Give us code and give us sample data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Colon isn't a special character in python string output, but it is special to email headers. Try inserting a blank line in the output:

```
output = "\nPrint: Customer"
```

Comment: Thanks!  Knew it was an email issue, was backslashing etc and couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to make a few guesses:

1. The mail is actually being sent, but the body appears to be empty (You question doesn't say this).
2. You're not using the builtin python mailing library.
3. If you open the mail in your mail reader, and look at the headers, the "`print:`" line will be present.

If so, the problem is that you're not ending the mail headers with a "`\r\n`" pair, and the mail reader thinks that "`print:`" is a mail header, while "`print -`" is part of the body of a mal-formed email.

If you add the "`\r\n`" after your headers, everything should be fine.